# Use array values as other array index. illegal offset type

Tags: php

Hi i have 3 arrays in my JSON file

```
{
    "Temperatures": [26.00, 26.50, 26.50, 0.00, 0.00, 20.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00],
    "ThermoStatus": [0, 0, 0, -6, -6, -6, -3, -6, -6],
    "FurnaceArray": [{
            "Oven": {
                "Thermo": [1, 4],
                "SetPoint": 60.5
            },
            "Part": {
                "Thermo": [2, 3],
                "SetPoint": 60.5
            },
            "Outer": {
                "Thermo": [5],
                "SetPoint": 60.5
            },
            "TimerElapsed": 79,
            "HeaterOutput": 0.600,
            "ProgramPhase": 1,
            "HeaterState": 3,
            "OvenStatus": {
                "DoorOpened": true,
                "EmergencyPressed": false,
                "ProgramDone": false
            }
        },
        {
            "Oven": {
                "Thermo": [5, 6],
                "SetPoint": 60.5
            },
            "Part": {
                "Thermo": [7],
                "SetPoint": 60.5
            },
            "Outer": {
                "Thermo": [5],
                "SetPoint": 60.5
            },
            "TimerElapsed": 79,
            "HeaterOutput": 0.600,
            "ProgramPhase": 1,
            "HeaterState": 3,
            "OvenStatus": {
                "DoorOpened": true,
                "EmergencyPressed": false,
                "ProgramDone": false
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I've combined the Oven Thermo and the Part Thermo. Like this.

```
$comTemperatures = array($json->FurnaceArray[0]->Oven->Thermo , $json->FurnaceArray[0]->Part->Thermo);
```

And now i want to use $comTemperatures as an index for Thermostatus. How can i show the temperatures which the index is given in $comTemperatures

i now have this

```
foreach ($comTemperatures as $value) {
    if ($thermostatus[$value] == 0) {
        echo $temperatures[$value];
    }
}
```

but i get an error "illegal offset type" at the foreachloop.
Can someone help me

Comment: You get an illegal offset type because `$comTemperatures` is an array which contains 2 other arrays, so in the foreach `$value` is itself an array which cannot be a valid array key. What is your expected format of `$comTemperatures`?

Comment: Sorry my English is not very good but what do you mean with expected format?

Comment: I've posted an answer of what I suspect is what you meant to do, but feel free to respond if it's not what you needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly:

```
$jsonArray = json_decode($jsonString); //$jsonString is the JSON you shared

$thermostatus = $jsonArray->ThermoStatus;
$temperatures = $jsonArray->Temperatures;
//Merge two arrays into one instead of making one array of arrays 
$comTemperatures = array_merge($json->FurnaceArray[0]->Oven->Thermo , $json->FurnaceArray[0]->Part->Thermo);     
foreach ($comTemperatures as $value) {
   if ($thermostatus[$value] == 0) {
        echo $temperatures[$value];
    }
}
```

Example at: https://eval.in/859257